# Container-Fluid has little padding on each side of the cols

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want a fluid container which goes over 100% of my screen. The problem is, that bootstraps ads a padding to each col so that the total width is bigger than 100%. Adding a "no-padding" class to every col maybe works but can't be the correct solution, or?

The strange thing is, that it works in my jsFiddle correctly. In my project not:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xWp5/)

In my project:

```
<div id="section1">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">test</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">test</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">test</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">test</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">test</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#section1 {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

It looks like this: [image]

Comment: You want your text to be right up against the side of the browser window?

Comment: Yep exactly. Every col without a padding

Comment: Maybe this  - http://jsfiddle.net/CCYLe/1/

Answer (score 3):

Just add a zero padding to `container-fluid`:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5xWp5/3/

Note I also applied it to the right side as I assume you want it there too.

Comment: I've also tried what you suggested, but it didn't worked, but I know saw that's not the container-fluid class, it's the row class which creates this weird offset. Still thanks :)

Comment: What isn't working exactly? `container-fluid` adds 15px padding, `row` removes 15px and `col-*` adds 15px. So if you remove it from `container-fluid`, it balances out.

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but the row gave me a strange offset on the right which created a h-scrollbar. .row {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container-fluid [class^="col"] {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
} gave me the desired result